# Building a bool query with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, nativequery

I'm trying to make a bool must match query in java with this structure

```
GET offers/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "offerLine": "Technology"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried this and I'm getting a null value:

```
private NativeQueryBuilder prepareElasticQuery(OfferRequest request){
    BoolQuery.Builder bqb = QueryBuilders.bool();
    bqb.must(m->m.match(ma->ma.field("offerLine").query(request.getOfferLine())));
    NativeQueryBuilder nqb= new NativeQueryBuilder().withQuery(bqb.build()._toQuery());
    return nqb;
}
```

The bool query gets this value :

```
BoolQuery: {"must":[{"match":{"offerLine":{"query":"Technology"}}}]}
```

And I can't seem to find an alternative to the value() method since it's deprecation.
Any clues as to how I can build it properly?

Edit: That's the proper way. My problem is with further handling the results.

Comment: `"offerLine": "Technology"` and `"offerLine":{"query":"Technology"}` are equivalent

Comment: You're right. I've found out that I'm getting hits but am not handling them properly so I end up with an empty result list. Thank you

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do that:

```java
public SearchRequest prepareElasticQuery(OfferRequest request) {
  SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("offers");
  searchRequest.source(new SearchSourceBuilder()
    .query(
      QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(
          QueryBuilders.matchQuery("offerLine", request.getOfferLine()
        )
      )
    )
  );
  return searchRequest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've figured it out previously and that wasn't my error.